# Get~Set value from different ViewControllers XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, retain, instance-variables

I have a two ViewControllers

- Level4ViewController
- Level5ViewController

In `Level4ViewController` I have a `NSNumber *averagePred;` I would like to get and set the value of `averagePred` from `Level5ViewController`.

I have already entered the `@property (nonatomic, retain)` ... for each.

How can I manage this, I've tried just putting the properties in my AppDelegate and using:

```
appDelegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

This didn't seem to work, and I would like to be able to get this sorted.

And a final part, if anyone can help me on:

I have:

`NSNumber *averagePred;` In my header file

In the methods I have a `float average;` and using `averagePred = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:average];` didn't work. Can anyone help me out here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Level5VC needs a reference to Level4VC, so it can do this:

```
   myLevel4VC.averagePred = 159.3;
```

You can give level5 the reference by passing it into a custom constructor, or by having a level4VC ivar in level5 that is set by whoever invokes level5.

Comment: Level4ViewController *controller; -- controller.averagePred ?